# A "complementary" topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis

If $(X, \tau)$ is an [Alexandrov topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology) then arbitrary intersection of open sets are open, and likewise arbibtrary unions of closed sets are closed, so we can define a topology $(X, \tau')$ as 
$$
 U \in \tau' \mbox{ iff } U^C \in \tau 
$$
i.e. $U$ is open in the new topology if $U^C$ is closed in the old topology. Beside them being themselve an Alexandrov topology, is there something interesting to know about the new topology $\tau'$ and it's relation to $\tau$?

Comment: Something interesting is kind of wide. Do you need the "something interesting" for something else more specific?

Comment: You probably know that Alexandrov topologies correspond to preordered sets. So the dual topology corresponds to reversing the preorder. I'm not sure what kind of properties you are looking for but obviously in general there can be as little or as much relation between the duals as you wish. E.g. on one hand you can consider spaces having only clopen sets, so these spaces are self-dual; on the other hand, you can consider spaces with no proper clopen sets which can have very different duals. Also, remember that finite topological spaces are all Alexandrov, so try to look at those as well.

Comment: I hoped there are some relations for example between the compact subsets. The specific example I had in mind is the topology on the free monoid $A^*$ given by the base sets $A^*uA^*$, this is investigated in the following paper and could be interpreted as specifying factors which occur in the open sets. But now I want to specify factors which do not occur, such a set has the form $(A^*u_1A^* \cup A^*u_2 A^* \cup \ldots \cup A^* u_k A^*)^C$ where $u_1, \ldots, u_k$ are the forbidden factors. These basis sets are complementary to the other base sets, and furthermore the original is Alexandrov

Comment: the link to the paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439758690143X